# How to uninstall the following packages?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, uninstall, delete

so I wanted to uninstall the following packages, specifically libnvidia-compute 440 one.
What commands do I give to remove it and how do I zero down on its location?

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
rc  cuda-nvtx-10-1                             10.1.243-1                                       amd64        NVIDIA Tools Extension
rc  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64                435.21-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                          amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
```

Running dpks -L gives many paths and Iam confused which one it exactly is.

```
$dpkg -L libnvidia-compute-440:amd64
/.
/etc
/etc/OpenCL
/etc/OpenCL/vendors
/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.440.82
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-compiler.so.440.82
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.440.82
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.440.82
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.440.82
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.440.82
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-compute-440
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-compute-440/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libnvidia-compute-440/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1
```

Comment: Ritik, please don't forget to accept the correct answer so others with the same problem will see it as so.

Comment: sure thing, my bad @Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall it by

```
sudo apt purge libnvidia-compute-440
```

Comment: Oh wow yeah this worked! This was way more simple.  Thanks a lot. Also adding to my previous question, this package was apparently causing the conflict. i had a newer version of libnvidia compute than the driver supported